# Wordpress: open page at bottom of parent page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, menu, nav

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and can't think anymore.

I've created a template for a particular page for event menus and within that page I have a sub menu.  This sub menu has event menus.  For the purposes of example: Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3

These menu items are their own pages.

The submenu should open the pages in this template.  Page layout example below:

```
Header
Main Nav
Banner Image
Content for Events
Event Menus (Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3)
Menu Content
Footer
```

Menu Content switches out by clicking on the menu items, but the Content for Events stays static.

I currently have it working by adding a $_GET variable to the end of the links, but I've hard coded the menu.  I don't want this because then the client can't make their own menu changes and edit their menus.  (The amount of changes so far has been ridiculous.)

I've put the Event Menus and Menu Content into another nested loop, theoretically so it reacts inside the loop, though initial tests with this have failed.

I'd really like to keep the dynamic nature of Wordpress' menu system, but can't get this to work without hard coding.

At this point I'd be happy with direction on where to research.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your menu content look like? Is it something a client could edit reasonably in a Wordpress Post/Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put a few notches in my oop and WP programming since asking this question. I think the better way to do this is a custom post type and change the wp_query object with parameters based on the link which can probably just be controlled by post ID. But it would still allow for a menu to be added to the "archive" page that controls the posts. Ultimately allowing client control of the menu, but still having a dynamic ability.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML for the menu content is not too unwieldy, you could potentially drop each menu into a Wordpress Page, where the client could edit it. Simply create a Wordpress page for each menu, drop in your menu content, save it, and make a note of the Page's ID number.

Then, in your template, you can pull in the menu content by getting the Page with something like this:

```
<?php
    // Menu One is content in Page ID # 14
    $menu_one = get_post(14); 
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $menu_one->post_content);
?>
```

For your reference, get_post on Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

On your actual page, what you could do instead of using a GET to grab each menu, is just go ahead and load all 3 menus on page load. Using CSS, you can hide the two you don't want at first and just show the default one. Then using some JavaScript events on the menu item links, you can show the clicked-on menu and hide the other two.